# Copy date format cell to datatable excellibrary

Tags: c#, excel, excellibrary

I'm developing a program in C#, is a desktop application.
I have a problem, I'm using excellibrary to open an excel and copy the data to a datatable, but I have a cell with date in format mm/dd/yyyy, but when i display the datatable in datagridview this information change to a number, for example:

02/07/1984 -> 30865

this is my code, I hope somebody could help me!

```
private DataTable ConvertToDataTable(string FilePath)
        {
            string file = FilePath;
            // open xls file
            Workbook book = Workbook.Open(file);
            Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            // traverse rows by Index
            for (int rowIndex = sheet.Cells.FirstRowIndex; rowIndex <= sheet.Cells.LastRowIndex; rowIndex++)
            {

                Row row = sheet.Cells.GetRow(rowIndex);
                object[] temparray = new object[row.LastColIndex + 1];
                for (int colIndex = row.FirstColIndex;
                   colIndex <= row.LastColIndex; colIndex++)
                {
                    Cell cell = row.GetCell(colIndex);
                    temparray[colIndex] = cell.Value;
                }
                if (rowIndex == 0)
                {
                    foreach (object obj in temparray)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(obj.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(temparray);
                }

            }

            return dt;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number you see is OLE Automation Date, you need to convert that number to `DateTime` by using [`DateTime.FromOADate Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(30865); //dt = {02/07/1984 12:00:00 AM}
```

To use that method in your current code, you have to go through each column's value and for date index, parse the value to `DateTime` and then add it to the `DataTable`

Comment: Thank you, your answer was helpful for me, i hope other people that face the same problem see your answer